# How to have a perfect align on the output Python?

Tags: python, nltk

I have two list, and I want to print side by side both of them.

```
list1 =[(15, 'dog'), (10, 'leopard'), (5, 'bird')] 
list1 =[(20, 'table'), (23, 'PC'), (13, 'TV')]
```

When a print them my output is horrible:

```
List1:                                    List2:
dog                 Freq --> 15           table           Freq --> 20
leopard                 Freq --> 10       PC            Freq --> 23
bird                Freq --> 5            TV            Fre1 --> 13
```

I what something like that:

```
List1:                                    List2:
dog                 Freq --> 15           table         Freq --> 20
leopard             Freq --> 10           PC            Freq --> 23
bird                Freq --> 5            TV            Fre1 --> 13
```

I can't use modules for make table.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Why can't you "use modules"?

Comment: because this is a project for an exam, and the specific is "YOU CAN'T USE MODULES!"

Comment: Wow, that is pretty specific. Good thing it's in caps as well – perhaps your instructor was afraid someone would not notice it. Next time make sure to mention any restrictions in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `center()`, `ljust()` and `rjust()` methods for strings. They work generally in this way:

```
`str.ljust(width[, fillchar])`
```

where `fillchar` will be the character you pick can also be a sequence of characters) and `width` is the total lenght of the output (content + spacing). The main difference between those three method lies in the positioning of the string you want to justify (centered, left-justified or right-justified).